# Using MQTT broker for an E-commerce mobile application

Tags: android, web-services, backend, mqtt, messagebroker

We have made a decision to use a MQTT broker (for example emqtt) which connects mobile applications to the business logic server using MQTT protocol. In fact, all operations such as loading products, searching, login and so forth are done by channels on which business server have subscribed.

I am not still positive about this decision. We mainly choose MQTT broker because it is appropriate for handling notifications. However, considering that loading large data (such as products which include pictures and long texts) should be done by helping MQTT broker too, I would personally think maybe it is better to use MQTT broker merely for notifications and restful web services for other operations such as loading data.

I would be really grateful if you help me solving this dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest RESTful web services for your application's general needs, as MQTT is completely asynchronous you might not able to serve some instant requests.
I work in e-commerce and we use REStful APIs for most of our needs and started using MQTT for notifications alone.